# array length using pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, pass-by-reference

Array length can be calculated using `*(&arr+1)-arr` which then simplifies to `(&arr)[1]-arr` which further simplifies to `1[&arr]-arr`.

But when the length is calculated in a function different from where memory allocation has been done, wrong results are computed.

For instance,

```
#include <iostream> 
#define ARRAY_SIZE(arr) (1[&arr]-arr)      
using namespace std;

void func(int *arr)
{
    cout<<ARRAY_SIZE(arr)<<endl;
}

int main()
{
    int arr[]={1,2,3,4,5};
    cout<<ARRAY_SIZE(arr)<<endl;
    func(arr);
}
```

This gives the output:

```
5
8
```

What accounts for such strange behaviour?

Comment: It's not strange if you understand how your `*(&arr+1)-arr` trick works.

Comment: Does "arrays are not pointers" help?

Comment: Is that output from the actual code you posted, or the output from some similar code using `char *` instead of `int *`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [c++ - length of array inside class function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16618221/c-length-of-array-inside-class-function) or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328223/sizeof-array-passed-as-parameter

Comment: "further simplifies" ??!!

Comment: @MatsPetersson it is the actual code.

Comment: I am truly curious about where it is that people find this stupid way of computing array sizes when learning C++.

Comment: Because most C++ tutorials are C in C++ with brief mention of classes later on tutorials.

Comment: @Neil Even in C you can do better than that :( http://stackoverflow.com/a/12784339/46642

Comment: @CharlesBailey x[y]=*(x+y)=*(y+x)=y[x]. If the comment was sarcastic, i said simplifies because 2 parentheses are saved in this conversion.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes I wouldn't use this method for daily purposes. It was something new with an interesting mechanism.

Comment: @sudeepdino008: I am surprised that you consider `1[&a]-a` simpler that `(&a + 1) - a`. But the explanation appears to be that you consider "simpler" == "fewer parentheses".

Comment: Simpler means easier to understand. 1[&a] is very obscure syntax that will confuse many people.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Array length can be calculated using *(&arr+1)-arr

Only if `arr` is actually an array. Within `func`, `arr` is a pointer, so this dereferences a random word of memory to give undefined behavoiur.

There is no way to tell the size of an array given just a pointer to its first element. You could pass the array by reference:

```
template <size_t N>
void func(int (&arr)[N]) {
    cout<<ARRAY_SIZE(arr)<<endl;
    cout<<N<<endl;               // equivalent, and less weird
}
```

Using the same technique, we can reimplement `ARRAY_SIZE` without resorting to the preprocessor or any bizarre pointer arithmetic:

```
template <size_t N>
size_t ARRAY_SIZE(int (&arr)[N]) {
    return N;
}
```

Comment: In C++11, I would make that second one use a template T for the type, and make it constexpr to boot. C++03 can get the same effect (a constant expression that only works on arrays), but requires some `sizeof` [trickery](http://ideone.com/VzUndj).

Comment: @DaveS In C++11 you would use `std::array` instead

Comment: Actually, if `arr` is a pointer, what you get from the expression `*(&arr+1)-arr` is not its size but undefined behavior. The OP got the result of 8 which may seem a plausible value for the size of `int*`, but actually it is a mere coincidence. If the code was compiled without optimization and run on a x86, this is a very likely result because the expression `*(&arr + 1)` must have picked the caller's saved EBP.

Comment: @AndreyChernyakhovskiy: You're right; I didn't think too hard about what that nonsense would do to a pointer.

Answer (score 3):

In `main()` the compiler knows that `arr` is an array of size `5 * sizeof(int)`. In `func()` all the compiler knows is that `arr` is a pointer to a block of memory - it has no information about how big the array is, or even that it is an array (it could just be a chunk of memory allocated via `malloc()`, for example).

Answer (score 3):

When you pass your array to a function, it decays to a pointer and knowledge of its size is lost. func can take an array of any size, so how the size be determined? You must either pass the size of the array as an extra parameter, or use a data structure such as std::vector or (C++11) std::array, which keep track of their size.